# place CCSprite by percentage

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am searching for a way to place a *sprite* via `objective-c` in **percentage** based on the parents dimensions. Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
sprite.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
sprite.position.x = .2f;  // 20% of parent's width
sprite.position.y = .45f; // 45% of parent's height
```

make certain that sprite has a parent i.e. has been added to another node.

obcit. not tested, from memory. With cocos2d 3.x.

Comment: `sprite.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized; ` solved it. thank you very much… don't have enough votes to vote up your answer though…